# How to have Frontend Layout determine columns and backend layout?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

Is there a way to have the Frontend layout determine the Backend layout, template file and columns?

At the moment I have the following code that allows you to set the Backend layout and it uses the appropriate template file. But this gets very messy when there are different column positions for each layout.

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    #format = html
    file= fileadmin/templates/example/partials/example_home.html    
    partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/example/partials/
    layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/example/layouts/
    variables {

      # Assign the Columns
      main < styles.content.get
      main.select.where = colPos = 0

      news < styles.content.get
      news.select.where = colPos = 1
      }
    }
}


# Assign the Template files with the Fluid Backend-Template
page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject {
  key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
  key.override.field = backend_layout

  # Set the default Template
  default = TEXT
  default.value = fileadmin/templates/example/partials/example_home.html

  # Set a second Template
  23 = TEXT
  23.value = fileadmin/templates/example/partials/example_internal.html


}
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. You are using the backend_layout. Each backend_layout could have its own presentation in FE. Why should the FE Layout determine how the BE looks like? I mean, usually it is a on the other way around. You choose your BE layout, it determines the columns and you prepares a FE view for that. And in Fluid there are the "Layouts" to use for that so then you can pick up different parts from a template.

Comment: @AndrásOttó Ok, well if we forget about the frontend layout part, how do I set a different colPos depending on what backend layout is selected?

Comment: @AndrásOttó Also, what do you do if you have two different templates that use the same backend layout?

Answer (score 2):

Not messy at all, here's a real world example:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
  file.stdWrap.cObject {
    key.data = pagelayout

    default = TEXT
    default.value = {$customPagesTemplatePath}/Standard.html

    1 = TEXT
    1.value = {$customPagesTemplatePath}/Home.html

    2 = TEXT
    2.value = {$customPagesTemplatePath}/Landing.html

    10 = TEXT
    10.value = {$customPagesTemplatePath}/NewsDetail.html

    11 = TEXT
    11.value = {$customPagesTemplatePath}/LandingMini.html

    12 = TEXT
    12.value = {$customPagesTemplatePath}/FullWidth.html
  }
  layoutRootPath = {$customPagesLayoutPath}
  partialRootPath = {$customPagesPartialPath}

}
```

Think about it like this:

- As you say, forget about frontend layout. That's legacy; be layout serves for BE and FE.
- If a page was a city, the colPos would be the street. Or rather, imagine the Backend is a map you're drawing, and the frontend is a LEGO City you build according tho that map :-)) If it's OK, I'll stick with that metaphor.

ColPos is a determined part of a page where a record lives. If you can, take a look at the tt_content table in the database: you'll see that colPos is just a column with a number. So in the city "Page 1", there's a street called "colPos 7", and it contains some records (those would be houses). With the be_layout wizard in TYPO3 you'll create an administrative map of that city: how the editor should see these streets.

In the `FLUIDTEMPLATE` you call depending on the selected be_layout, you will create the city itself; the rendered frontend.

Here's another real world example for such a fluid template (Home.html):

```
<f:render partial="Mobilenav" />
<f:render partial="Header"/>

<div class="row">
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.home-teaser" />
</div>

<aside>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="fp-teaser-outer small-48 medium-24 large-12 columns">
          <div class="fp-teaser-box-wrapper">
            <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.home-something" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fp-teaser-outer small-48 medium-24 large-12 columns">
          <div class="fp-teaser-box-wrapper">
            <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.home-somethingelse" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fp-teaser-outer small-48 medium-24 large-12 columns">
          <div class="fp-teaser-box-wrapper">
            <div class="fp-teaser-box">
              <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.home-news-plugin-title" />
              <div class="fp-teaser-hr"></div>
              <div class="fp-teaser-content">
                <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.home-news" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fp-teaser-outer small-48 medium-24 large-12 columns">
          <div class="fp-teaser-box-wrapper">
            <div class="fp-teaser-box">
              <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.home-blog-plugin-title" />
              <div class="fp-teaser-hr"></div>
              <div class="fp-teaser-content">
                <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.home-blog" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>

<f:render partial="Footer"/>
```

... well, but where's the correlation with the colPos?
Nowhere yet! I (while being positive that there are other approaches) do this in TypoScript:

```
lib.home-something < styles.content.get
lib.home-something {
  select.where = colPos = 7
}
```

So by this we prepare content for the fluid template: get all content of that page's column 7 (using  the extension fluid_styled_content) and put it into a "lib" content object.

That's then inserted into the page via the `f:cObject` viewhelper:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.home-something" />
```

Like this, all houses in 7th street are put into the city in exactly this location – and thus rendered in your page.

Comment: I'm having two problems with this: 1) Can you have 'home-something' be in colPos 7 in one layout but colPos 6 on another? 2) What do you do if you have 2 fluid templates that share the same BE layout?

Comment: 1) this is just naming - yes. you're free to set that up as you wish. what you can't do is have the SAME content element / record in two different places. As you can't have the same house in 6th and 7th street. You can put two identical houses in the two streets, though. Or, as it's computing, mirror your house from 6th street into 7th street

Comment: 2) the template just says how the content is rendered. you can make as many templates for the same content as you wish. your situation is probably that you want to apply one template to a page in some cases, but another in other cases? and you don't know how to pass that information (which template to use) along? well, you'll have to bring in more logic into your TypoScript; e.g. "if this GET parameter is set, then choose this different BE Layout". I'd recommend setting up a separate question for that.

Comment: So for 1) You're saying I should simply name the columns  to be specific to their template eg 'home1maincontent' and 'home2maincontent' (assuming I had two home pages)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "naming columns". Probably yes. The standard answer would be "if it works for you, it's fine". I'd recommend to get more background on fluid / TypoScript, then everything will become clearer. Or practice, which is what you're doing. Just keep experimenting :-)

Comment: By naming columns I mean like your example 'home-something'. If 'home-something' is also in layout 2 but in a different position, do I need to make a 'home-something2' or is there a way to set the colPos  like this: 2.home-something.colPos = ?

Comment: I still think you're missing something. Consider posting a new question with a precise example

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically,

```
$backendLayout=$GLOBALS['TSFE']->cObj->getData('pageLayout');
```

If `None` was selected in the backend [`-1`], it will output `'none'`.
If nothing was selected it will output `'default'`. Otherwise it will output the correct backend layout prefixed with your extension, taking into account subpage layouts up the page ancestry chain.